# Avoid linux out-of-memory application teardown

Tags: linux, low-memory

I'm finding that on occasion my Linux box runs out of memory and it starts tearing down random processes to deal with it.

I'm curious what administrators do to avoid this?  Is the only real solution to up the amount of memory (will upping the swap alone help?), or is there better ways to set up the box with software to avoid this?  (i.e., quotas, or some such?).

Comment: I found an answer here : https://serverfault.com/questions/362589/effects-of-configuring-vm-overcommit-memory Patrick response is very instructive

Answer (score 63, accepted):

By default Linux has a somewhat brain-damaged concept of memory management: it lets you allocate more memory than your system has, then randomly terminates a process when it gets in trouble. (The actual semantics of what gets killed are more complex than that - Google "Linux OOM Killer" for lots of details and arguments about whether it's a good or bad thing).

---

To restore some semblance of sanity to your memory management:

1. Disable the OOM Killer (Put `vm.oom-kill = 0` in /etc/sysctl.conf)
2. Disable memory overcommit (Put `vm.overcommit_memory = 2` in /etc/sysctl.conf)
   Note that this is a trinary value: 0 = "estimate if we have enough RAM", 1 = "Always say yes", 2 = "say no if we don't have the memory")

These settings will make Linux behave in the traditional way (if a process requests more memory than is available malloc() will fail and the process requesting the memory is expected to cope with that failure).

Reboot your machine to make it reload `/etc/sysctl.conf`, or use the `proc` file system to enable right away, without reboot:

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

Comment: It's not Linux thats braindamaged, but the programmers that allocate the memory, never to use it. Java VMs are notorious with this. I, as an admin who manages servers runing Java apps wouldn't survive one second without overcommit.

Comment: Java programmers don't allocate unused memory, there is no malloc in java. I think you are confusing this with JVM settings like -Xms.  In any case, increasing virtual memory size by adding swap space is a much safer solution than overcommiting.

Comment: Note that this solution won't stop your system from running out of memory or killing processes. It will only revert you to traditional Unix behaviour, where if one process eats all your memory the next one that tries to malloc will not get any (and most likely crash). If you are unlucky that next process is init (or something else that is critical), which the OOM Killer generally avoids.

Comment: While these settings work in theory, in practice things aren't nearly as clean cut. A lot of applications rely on being able to overallocate memory. Unless you have extremely tight control over what is running on your systems, it can lead to all sorts of weird problems, including ones like pehrs describes.

Comment: jlliagre, i said Java VMs (Virtual Machines), not Java programs, although from an admin perspective it is the same :)

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning here that adding the above to `/etc/sysctl.conf` will likely only take effect on the next reboot; if you want to make changes *now* you should use the `sysctl` command with root permissions e.g. `sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=2`

Comment: Brain-damaged indeed; the OOM-killer just encourages sloppy programming that doesn't care about efficiency (hoarding memory) or error checking (checking for a failed malloc).

Comment: I cannot find the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file in `Lubuntu 16.04`.

Comment: It definitely is Linux that is brain damaged. The OOM killer by design, and unfixably, introduces the most severe instability into a server. Unfortunately, programs have come to rely on this behavior. This means that fixing it is very hard and Linux has to keep doing this forever.

Comment: On Ubuntu there is no vm.oom-kill, see https://superuser.com/questions/1150215/disabling-oom-killer-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: In case anyone is thinking about doing this to "fix" any OOM issues they are running into (like I did), PLEASE RECONSIDER. I set `vm.overcommit_memory = 2` with about 3.8 GiB RAM "free", but it destroyed my desktop session. Unfortunately, I added it to `/etc/sysctl.conf` as well, which meant that after I rebooted and re-logged on, it would get destroyed again. (Using Debian and Cinnamon in my case, but I'm not sure other desktop environments are any better in this regard.)

I think the idea is nice, but the reality is that many real-world applications rely on being able to overcommit memory.

Comment: @PerLundberg Did you get errors like `...traps: chrome[5867] trap invalid opcode...` in your applications? I got this all over the place after trying these settings on Debian 11. Some programs worked fine, others like Chrome, Chromium, games, Steam just crashed a few seconds after startup

Comment: @golimar Hmm, unsure. I only know that things like the Cinammon window manager seemed to die, making the system incredibly hard to use. :) I can't tell exactly what was logged in `/var/log/kern.log` if anything, unfortunately. :/

Comment: Where is the `vm.oom-kill` option documented? It seems to be named in lots of places on the net, but not to exist in the kernel (try issuing `sysctl vm.oom-kill`) nor in its documentation.

Comment: @usr you can easily disable memory overcommitment if you want. With that said, it's incorrect to blame Linux defaults because I doubt other systems work in any way different. I mean, look, right as writing these words I have `electron` process which takes 1.1T of VSS. And lots of skype processes, with each taking over 32G of virtual memory. And these are cross-platform applications, so there's no way they would survive on Windows had it been any different. These memory defaults are required for general purpose apps. Disabling it means having to manually inspect apps allowed to run.

Comment: @Hi-Angel point taken about being able to disable overcommitment. But, as your examples show, applications have come to rely on this behavior. Is it practical to disable this setting? Me, realizing that I am not a Linux pro, doubt it. On Windows, large virtual memory usage is also common but not for committed memory (only reserved). The comment by Per Lundberg seems to indicate this as well.

Comment: @usr whether it's practical depends on your usecase. For a typical user it is not, and you already know why. It may be more of a usecase for some odd embedded system, where each software component is closely reviewed regarding its work with virtual memory.

Comment: I would kill Linux Torwalds for implementing this thing if I saw him nearby

Answer (score 4):

You can disable overcommit, see http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt#514

Comment: An answer should be more than just a link to some lengthy linux kernel documentation file. -1

Answer (score 4):

The short answer, for a server, is buy and install more RAM.

A server that routinely enough experienced *OOM* (Out-Of-Memory) errors, then besides the VM (virtual memory) manager's overcommit sysctl option in Linux kernels, this is not a good thing.

Upping the amount of swap (virtual memory that has been paged out to disk by the kernel's memory manager) will help if the current values are low, and the usage involves many tasks each such large amounts of memory, rather than a one or a few processes each requesting a huge amount of the total virtual memory available (RAM + swap).

For many applications allocating more than two time (2x) the amount of RAM as swap provides diminishing return on improvement. In some large computational simulations, this may be acceptable if the speed slow-down is bearable.

With RAM (ECC or not) be quite affordable for modest quantities, e.g. 4-16 GB, I have to admit, I haven't experienced this problem myself in a long time.

The basics at looking at the memory consumption including using `free` and `top`, sorted by memory usage, as the two most common quick evaluations of memory usage patterns. So be sure you understand the meaning of each field in the output of those commands at the very least.

With no specifics of applications (e.g. database, network service server, real-time video processing) and the server's usage (few power users, 100-1000s of user/client connections), I cannot think of any general recommendations in regards to dealing with the OOM problem.

Comment: This is bad advice. Some programs (Java,gunicorn) by default will decide how much RAM they think they can grab when they are started. So its quite possible that you will NEVER have enough memory to avoid OOM. Unless you know that the system is short on RAM, th first step is to set overcommit_memory to 2, then reduce the overcommit_ratio.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ulimit to reduce the amount of memory a process is allowed to claim before it's killed. It's very usefull if your problem is one or a few run away processes that crashes your server.

If your problem is that you simply don't have enough memory to run the services you need there are only three solutions:

1. Reduce the memory used by your
   services by limiting caches and
   similar
2. Create a larger swap area. It will
   cost you in performance, but can buy
   you some time.
3. Buy more memory

Comment: Perfectly explained.

Answer (score 3):

Increasing the amount of physical memory may not be an effective response in all circumstances.

One way to check this is the 'atop' command. Particularly these two lines.

This is out server when it was healthy:

```
MEM | tot   23.7G | free   10.0G | cache   3.9G | buff  185.4M | slab  207.8M |
SWP | tot    5.7G | free    5.7G |              | vmcom  28.1G | vmlim  27.0G |
```

When it was running poorly (and before we adjusted overcommit_memory from 50 to 90, we would see behavior with vmcom running well over 50G, oom-killer blowing up processes every few seconds, and the load kept radically bouncing due to NFSd child processes getting blown up and re-created continually.

We've recently duplicated cases where multi-user Linux terminal servers massively over-commit the virtual memory allocation but very few of the requested pages are actually consumed.

While it's not advised to follow this exact route, we adjusted overcommit-memory from the default 50 to 90 which alleviated some of the problem. We did end up having to move all the users to another terminal server and restart to see the full benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Despite a lot of answers here - the best you can do as an administrator is to investigate everything in oom killer report(s) and clearly understand why it triggers. Then that should give you a clue about next steps. It may be related to OS config or maybe a problem with particular piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1655842) and solution was to use older / newer (fixed) kernel.

However at the time I could not reboot my machine so some kind of ugly workaround was to login as root and clear system caches with this command:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Answer (score -6):

@voretaq7 linux doesn't has brain-damaged concept of memory management, by default vm.overcommit_ratio is 0,

```
0       -   Heuristic overcommit handling. Obvious overcommits of
            address space are refused. Used for a typical system. It
            ensures a seriously wild allocation fails while allowing
            overcommit to reduce swap usage.  root is allowed to
            allocate slightly more memory in this mode. This is the
            default.
```

In this way, if you have 4GB of ram and you try to allocate 4.2 GB with malloc of virtual memory, your allocation will fail.

With vm.overcommit_ratio = 1

```
            1    -   Always overcommit. Appropriate for some scientific
            applications. Classic example is code using sparse arrays
            and just relying on the virtual memory consisting almost
            entirely of zero pages.
```

With vm.overcommit_ratio = 2

```
           2    -   Don't overcommit. The total address space commit
            for the system is not permitted to exceed swap + a
            configurable percentage (default is 50) of physical RAM.
            Depending on the percentage you use, in most situations
            this means a process will not be killed while accessing
            pages but will receive errors on memory allocation as
            appropriate.

            Useful for applications that want to guarantee their
            memory allocations will be available in the future
            without having to initialize every page.
```

So by default linux doesn't overcommit, if your application more memory then you have, maybe your code is buggy

Comment: You have contradicted yourself here. At the top you say "by default vm.overcommit_ratio is 0" and then at the bottom you say "by default linux doesn't overcommit". If the latter were true, vm.overcommit_ratio would be 2 by default!

Comment: vm.overcommit_ratio = 0, malloc doesn't alloc more memory than your physical ram, so for me that means don't overcommit, overcommit is when you can allocate more virtual than your physical ram

Comment: Yes, you have misunderstood.

Comment: you  misunderstood, the default 0, doesn't allocate to allocate more virtual memory than ram and 2 doesn't go over allow vm.overcommit_ratio + swap space, so if i misunderstood tell me what

Comment: if linux overcommit by default, why in my server with 8GB of ram, malloc fail to allocate 9GB of virtual memory? so i know you don't like my answer, but the true is linux doesn't overcommit by default and vm.overcommit_ratio = 0 means that. try for your self

Comment: Of course. "Obvious overcommits" are refused. The rest passes. You need to read more carefully.

Comment: maybe i don't speak very well, this is the @voretaq7 answer "By default Linux has a somewhat brain-damaged concept of memory management: it lets you allocate more memory than your system has", i don't think so, so as you know and like you told "Of course. "Obvious overcommits" are refused", so for me the answer isn't correct

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11898/discussion-between-c4f4t0r-and-michael-hampton)