# OOMK kills mysql and apache when there is still a lot[?] of mem

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avoid linux out-of-memory application teardown](https://serverfault.com/questions/141988/avoid-linux-out-of-memory-application-teardown)

let me first say that I'm pretty new ti *nix systems and even more to server management. Anyway, I've got a little problem.
I got VPS with 1gb mem, system is debian 6. I have few sites running on it, though some load can only be caused by one of them. 
Recently, OOMK started to kill mysql, causing wp and phpbb giving error that it can't connect to mysql server. 
Error itself is not good, especially if it happens at night and site becomes unavailable until I wake up and restart mysql.
I have probably bad line in my cron which can be cause of it all (again, I'm new to it)

```
    */20 * * * *    sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Well, if you need any information, let me know, since I don't really know which information can be useful here.
Also, I'd like to know if it's not too bad to have above cron task.

Comment: And you're looking to stop the OOMkills for mysql? Is that what you're after?

Comment: I'm looking for good/right solution (not some temp) to the kills of mysql and apache

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in running `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.
As Linux runs out of memory it will automatically remove the buffers and caches, so you're actually harming system performance by forcing removal of useful i/o caching.

You really need to look at what could be consuming all the memory. Look at the following possible culprits:

1. Apache - Max clients or number of servers too high. I presume you're running in pre-fork mode.
2. PHP - Max memory, max upload, number of database connections
3. Nightly cron jobs, like slocate
4. Mysql memory usage.

**UPD**
 MySQL may be being killed by OOMKiller but not actually the cause. It could be just the largest single memory consumer.

Comment: 1.  -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork" from apache2 -V so I assume it's pre-fork, so part of config `<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>`
2.  memory_limit = 256M , so not too much [?] , 3  - /usr/local/ispmgr/sbin/cron.sh sbin/eximquota.check.sh, /usr/local/ispmgr/sbin/cron.sh sbin/ihttpd.check.sh, /usr/local/ispmgr/sbin/cron.sh sbin/mgrctl -m ispmgr task.daily

Comment: , /usr/local/ispmgr/sbin/cron.sh sbin/update.sh ispmgr, /usr/local/ispmgr/sbin/dbcache, /usr/local/ispmgr/sbin/rotate,/usr/local/ispmgr/sbin/traffic.pl, mysqlcheck -u root -p"pwhere" --optimize --all-databases >/dev/null 2>&1, sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 4. For that I'd like your help to find memory usage parameters

Comment: AFAIK, if you have memory_limit = 256M and you have MaxClient = 150 then you potentially have 256MB * 150 = 38400MB! This may be the source of your problem. Reduce max_memory to the absolute minimum required and lower MaxClients to match.

Comment: uh, i doubt that would be default configuration if that was the case

Comment: The default memory_limit ranges from 8MB to 128MB depending on PHP version so I think my theory is correct that 256MB is too high for your 1GB VM. Of course each process shouldn't consume 256MB but you may have some bad code or a memory leak. Why don't you run `ps aux` and see how much memory each Apache process is running and prove me wrong?

Comment: See http://groups.drupal.org/node/233663 which backs my suspicion

Answer (score -1):

Easy fix:  Put more memory in the server.

But the question is why is the server running out of memory. Are you using InnoDB? Is the buffer pool size the right size? etc. More information is needed to help you out, to start with the output of htop and the mysql log.

Comment: lol, eh. I doubt there is need of memory for not really big site. I'm pretty sure it's like misconfiguration fault. As for more information, of course I know, that's why I said to tell me which is needed ;)

Comment: And yeas, I'm using InnoDB (it seems) , though I don't know where to check for buffer poll param,/etc/mysql/my.conf don't seem to have it. as for long, i found none. And what is htop? you meant top?

Comment: Htop is an advanced version of the "top" command. You can logon to mysql in CLI and enter the following command "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'; "